# SNAP vs. Snapshot - Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

This may sound like a dumb question but I'm trying to learn Firebase Database and keep coming across the word "snap" in the code examples.  When I look up the meaning of "snap" I can't find any definition which seems really odd to me.  So I'm wondering if it is shorthand for "snapshot" or does it have a completely different meaning.

Example: `query.on('value', snap => { // do something });`

Where can I find a definition for the meaning of snap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an argument name for a function you are defining. So its completely arbitrary.

Look up the definition of [`on` in the API reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Query#on).

That tells you that the second parameter is:

> callback: (a: DataSnapshot, b?: string | null) => any
>
> A callback that fires when the specified event occurs. **The callback
> will be passed a DataSnapshot**. For ordering purposes, "child_added",
> "child_changed", and "child_moved" will also be passed a string
> containing the key of the previous child, by sort order, or null if it
> is the first child.

And it links to the [definition of a DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.DataSnapshot):

> A DataSnapshot contains data from a Database location.
>
> Any time you read data from the Database, you receive the data as a
> DataSnapshot. A DataSnapshot is passed to the event callbacks you
> attach with on() or once(). You can extract the contents of the
> snapshot as a JavaScript object by calling the val() method.
> Alternatively, you can traverse into the snapshot by calling child()
> to return child snapshots (which you could then call val() on).
>
> A DataSnapshot is an efficiently generated, immutable copy of the data
> at a Database location. It cannot be modified and will never change
> (to modify data, you always call the set() method on a Reference
> directly).

Comment: Thank you, as a new user sometimes the obvious answer is not at all clear, between callbacks and parameters being passed, I had no clue where to look.  And yet all the example videos about FireBase that I have watched did not describe "on".  Really appreciate the feedback.